# How to prevent data shown in dev tool chrome in production env

Tags: node.js, angular, google-chrome, ionic-framework, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

If I go to devtools in chrome and go to Network tab and check Fetch/XHR , I can see data received from server. Well , following screen shot is from prod env :).

Kindly guide/advice.

I have developed my application in ionic/angular.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: Data you provide to the client application through HTTP(S) communication  will always be visible to the end user.  Client application cannot provide security of the data. If there's any data that should not be accessed by the end user, you have to implement the security measure on the server, not the client. Server must provide only the data the user is authorised to access. Devtools is only a convenient way to display the data, which the user still have access to by other means - you basically send the data to them, therefore consider them visible.